Change coordinate system of a layer so that some of its points match their exact location in QGIS
I have a layer with several polygons and points, but their coordinates are completely wrong (this layer was extracted from a "bad" source).
For a few points of this layer (let us call them reference points), I have the exact coordinates (as attributes).
How can I "align" the whole layer (I guess it means modify its coordinate system) so that the reference points are situated as close to their exact coordinates as possible?
I use QGIS.

Why do you think it was a "bad" source? Please show more details, maybe a few "bad" points and their tie "good" points.

A) Try to find out the CRS the layer was created in or B) use Georeferencer: https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/georeferencer.html#index-0

Sometimes bad data is bad data, and simply cannot be corrected.

Thank you for your replies. By bad source, I mean that this data comes from an AutoCAD file without geographical coordinates (thus the points are simply situated in a rectangle). I tried Goereferencer and then Vector Bender, and the latter worked. Thanks!
